# Smoothing text ImagickDraw?

Tags: php, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagick

How to make the text here such as in the picture?

[image: Anti-aliased text]

I do not get anti-aliased text:

[image: Without anti-aliasing]

**How to make the same smoothing as in the first picture?**

My code:

```
$body = 'Company Name';
$pointsize = 10*1.4; //PT to pointsize
$fill = '000000';
$width = 170;

$canvas = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$color = new ImagickPixel($fill);

$draw->setFont('fonts/Arial/Arial.ttf');
$draw->setFontSize($pointsize);
$draw->setFillColor($color);
$draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
$draw->setTextAntialias(true);

$data = $canvas->queryFontMetrics($draw, $body);
$draw->annotation(0, $data['ascender'], $body);
$draw->annotation(0, $data['ascender'], $body);

$canvas->newImage($width, $data['textHeight'], 'none');
$canvas->drawImage($draw);

$canvas->setImageFormat('png');

header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $canvas->getImageBlob();
```